# Memory Management For User Interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

I'm working on an app's user interface, and I'm doing it programmatically. I understand the idea behind retain cycles, and feel quite confident I could identify one, but Xcode is giving me warnings when I'm trying to avoid a retain cycle.

Essentially, I'm creating a property called `titleLabel` which will have my title, and in `viewDidLoad` I'm initializing it, and placing it on my view. The only problem is, I'm getting an Xcode warning that says:

> Assigning retained object to weak variable; object will be released after assignment

My property definition is as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel *titleLabel;
```

Obviously I could fix the Xcode warning by changing `weak` to `strong` in my property definition, but I believe that would create a retain cycle (from my understanding) because the button is holding onto the View Controller and the View Controller is holding onto the button.

Can anyone give me some insight as to how to do this properly?

Comment: This won't be a retain cycle because the button doesn't have a reference to the view controller however, if you want to keep the property as `weak` simply assign use a local variable when you allocate the label and assign it to the property after you have added it your view. The local variable will hold the reference until the method exits and the view will hold the strong reference afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is flawed.  If the label were to retain a reference to its view controller, you would have a retain cycle if the property were defined as `strong`.  However, views do not retain references to their view controllers, so there is no cycle.  Xcode is warning you correctly that your label reference will go away after the assignment.  You aren't even saved by adding it as a subview (which would retain it), because it's already released by the time you try.

The one quasi-exception to views not retaining references to controllers is with table and collection views, which have delegates and datasources which are usually their managing view controller.  However, those delegate/datasource properties are defined as `assign` properties (which has another set of problems) so there is no retain cycle there, either.

Comment: I don't know why I imagined views would retain the parent VC. So you're saying I don't have to worry about retain cycles if my labels are strong, correct?

Comment: Correct.  When defining `IBOutlet` properties to be used with storyboards or xibs, the common practice is to define them as `weak`.  This works because the xib-loading machinery ensures that a reference is kept somewhere.  Defining such properties as `strong` would interfere with cleanup, as the machinery has no way to affect that reference.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can set property to strong which will retain its memory and when your view will disappear call then you can set this object to nil which will release its memory.

Comment: You don't need to nil properties in order to release them.  If the view controller has the only strong reference, and it's going away, then the last strong reference is going away and ARC will automatically release the memory.  That's half the purpose of ARC.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a UI element and add it as a subview to parent view. The Parent view keeps a strong reference to sub View. In your case, you could just create a UILabel variable within your function and add it to the parent.

You could then declare a weak property that keeps a reference to this newly created label. This way, the parent view "owns" the label, and it takes care of cleaning up the label when the parent view goes off screen.

```
@interface MasterViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,weak) UILabel * theLabel;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel* myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
    self.theLabel = myLabel;
}
```